# reading contents of file when file uploading in php

Tags: php

I am using javascript to upload files in php.the sample code shown here

```
<div id="upload"> 
    <input type="button"  onclick="uploadFile();" value="+">
    <script>
        var count=0;

        function uploadFile()
        {
            count=count+1;
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            var text = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var remove = document.createElement("INPUT");
            text.setAttribute("type", "text");
            text.setAttribute("name", "description_"+count);
            text.setAttribute("value", "file description");
                // remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
                // remove.setAttribute("value", "-");
                // x.setAttribute("name","");
            x.setAttribute("type", "file");
            upload.appendChild(br);
            upload.appendChild(x);
            upload.appendChild(text);
            upload.appendChild(remove);

        }
    </script>
</div>
```

but here how to get uploaded files contents(means descriptions) at another page?.Here I am using the below php code.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    "<br/>";
    echo $key, ' => ', $value, "<br/>";
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your for loop should look like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $key. ' => '. $value. "<br/>";
}
```

Use dots `.` instead of commas `,`. Refer to [**this about concatenation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

And regarding your code: what you're basically doing is treating `$_POST` as an array/collection and iterating through its values, retrieving the key as `$key` and the value as `$value`.